# how to resolve pullasync fail in azure?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, azure

I have created a wpf windows application, I was able to connect with locally created Azure Mobile service using visual Studio 2015.

Now as soon as I changed the application to work in offline mode from [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data/) application could not load stating pull failed.

error details:

```
message :
Hide   Copy Code

The request could not be completed.  (Bad Request)   

{Method: GET, RequestUri: 'http://localhost:59675/tables/TodoItem?$filter=(updatedAt ge datetimeoffset'1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000%2B00:00')&$orderby=updatedAt&$skip=0&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true', Version: 1.1, Content: , Headers:
{
X-ZUMO-FEATURES: QS,OL
X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: b27d76a8-6c70-48c2-b5a9-76b1540d960f
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: ZUMO/2.0
User-Agent: (lang=Managed; os=Windows; os_version=6.2.0.9200; arch=Win32NT; version=2.0.31125.0)
X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/2.0 (lang=Managed; os=Windows; os_version=6.2.0.9200; arch=Win32NT; version=2.0.31125.0)
ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0
}}
```

Kindly help to resolve

Answer (score 0):

I have solve it with adding this key in Mobile App settings [image]

Or better use new NuGet packages:

Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client
and
Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore